# $A \in Gl(n,K)$ if and only if $A$ is a product of elementary matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to show the statement:

$A \in GL(n,K)$ if and only if $A$ is a product of elementary matrices.

I could show the reverse implication:

Suppose $A=T_1...T_m$ where each $T_k$ is an elementary matrix. An elementary matrix can be of the form:

1) $T_{ij}$ the matrix that swaps the rows $i,j$

2) $T_{\lambda i}$ the matrix that multiplies the row $i$ by a scalar $\lambda \neq 0$.

3) $T_{i+\lambda j}$ the matrix that to the row $i$ adds a multiple $\lambda$ of the row $j$ (with $j \neq i$).

It is very easy to see that each of these elementary matrices has an inverse:

$T_{ij}^{-1}=T_{ji}$

${T_{\lambda i}}^{-1}=T_{\lambda^{-1}i}$

${T_{i+\lambda j}}^{-1}=T_{i-\lambda j}$

So if I call $B={T_n}^{-1}...{T_1}^{-1}$, then $$BA=AB=Id_n$$

This proves $B=A^{-1}$, so $A \in GL(n,K).$

How can I show the other implication? Any suggestions or proofs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the elementary matrices corresponds to an allowable move in Gaussian elimination. That is to say, each elementary row operation corresponds to left multiplication by one of the elementary matrices. 
If $A$ is an invertible matrix, then the reduced form of the matrix is the identity: therefore, there is a collection of elementary matrices $T_{i}$ such that $(T_{1}...T_{n})A = I$. And so $A = T_{n}^{-1}...T_{1}^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You've shown that if $A$ is product of elementary matrices, then $A$ is invertible. To show the converse, if $A$ is invertible, what is the row reduced echelon form of $A$?